# MySQL Number in KEY parameter creation

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I looked and some SQL scripts and wondered what the number in the braces behind the KEY operator means?

I provided a truncated sample of the script (from Wordpress), where you can see this in the 4th line.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_usermeta` (
  `umeta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`umeta_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: [Read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html), hit ctrl + f, look for "length". If you want the short version, it's the length of the index or how many characters will be read from that column and used for indexing.

Comment: @N.B. Thank you, that was the right pointer. Do you want to transform it into a full answer? Otherwise I'll try to summarize it later.

Comment: I'm lazy so feel free to summarize it in a proper answer, I'm glad that the pointer worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html):

> Indexes can be created that use only the leading part of column
> values, using col_name(length) syntax to specify an index prefix
> length:
>
> - Prefixes can be specified for CHAR, VARCHAR, BINARY, and VARBINARY columns.
> - BLOB and TEXT columns also can be indexed, but a prefix length must be given.
> - Prefix lengths are given in characters for nonbinary string types and in bytes for binary string types. That is, index entries consist of the first length characters of each column value for CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT columns, and the first length bytes of each column value for BINARY, VARBINARY, and BLOB columns.